# Use Ethernet when available and working, WiFi personal hotspot when not

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, ethernet, wifi-hotspot

My home Internet connection (via Ethernet) is unreliable - when it's working I can get 90 Mbps, but around 50% of the time from 12pm to 10pm it is not working. When the home Internet is not working, I turn on the personal hotspot on my phone and switch to it on my laptop. After a while, I check if the Internet is back up by pinging through the Ethernet interface.

```
ping -I enp4s0 google.com
```

If the Ethernet connection is working, I switch back to it.

However, data is expensive, so I don't want to use it if the Ethernet connection is working. Having to manually check if it's working and switching back-and-forth is a slow process.

I am asking to see if there's a tool that will automatically check if the Internet is working via one Interface, and route traffic through that interface. But if it is not working, then route traffic through a backup interface.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, but am looking for a generic Linux-based solution.

> Note that I am not asking how to switch to Ethernet *when it is plugged in*. The Ethernet cable is *always plugged in* but the Internet may not be reachable from it.

Comment: What's the port name for your hotspot? Can't finish the script without that.

Comment: @K7AAY I connect to the hotspot through WiFi so it'll be through the `wlp5s0` interface.

Answer (score 0):

No canned tool known. Therefore, suggest you write a script, to have [cron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/cron.8.html) run a job to [ping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ping.1.html) out *enp4s0* to **8.8.4.4** and **1.0.0.1** (just in case Google's taking a break). (I suggest that to eliminate the script getting fooled by a DNS problem.)

If you can connect, switch to *enp4s0* if you're not already using it.

If the answer include the word *unreachable* or times out, make sure you're using Mister Hotspot.

Comment: That's the logic I am looking for, but is there a _tool_ that does this? Or I'd have to write my own script?

Comment: See updated answer  w/ clarification, above.